# Laravel Token Preventing access to a page

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, token

I struggled implementing a search form on my website. I  finally got it done. But the problem is that if I click on the students link in the website, it doesn't let me. I have to manually type the address in the address bar to be able to visit this page.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/students //this is the actual link. but I have  manually type it like this.
```

When I type http://127.0.0.1:8000/students , a token automatically adds to the link.

`127.0.0.1:8000/students?_token=XLUB5ku5LenkhkMSuBv1Ibs4ElgdGiGxaeajOGkK&search`

I think the reason the reason is because of the get method. But how do I get this problem solved so that I can just click the link and visit the page without going through the token

Comment: you say click a link ... are you implementing a form or you just have a link?

Comment: I have the search form on the same page, After I write the code for searching the students database and implementing the code to accept data from the database, the token on the form prevents me from visiting the page unless I manually type the url in the address bar. By typing it, the token automatically gets added to the link.

Comment: that 'token' is a CSRF token which is not needed for `GET` requests

Comment: Let me delete and see